# Add .otf font to iphone application

Tags: ios, fonts, truetype

i'm trying to use a custom .otf font to my application, but don't work, i have tried the .ttf font and work, but the .otf don't, anyone can help me? there is a way to add .otf font? i read a lot of guide to add font, but for the .otf don't work, this is the font:

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Lobster

Comment: i think only ttf are allowed. Did you read anywhere that you can use .otf?

Comment: in all the guide i read, use the otf and ttf...i don't understand...

Comment: for any future readers, this guide fixed the issue for my otf font imports. my issue was that the target wasn't selected for the fonts. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122087/add-otf-font-to-iphone-application

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to ensure that you are using the correct name with fonts. It's tricky. Try to open the font with fontbook in mac, or the equivalent in windows. On a mac, when you open the font in fontbook, you should be able to see the exact name under "PostScript name":

[image: OTF Font Sample in Font Book]

Then, assuming that you have [properly added the font to your project](http://richardwarrender.com/2010/08/custom-fonts-on-ipad-and-iphone/), you should attempt to use it. For example, if you have a `*myTextField` pointer to a `UITextField`, and you want to use DIN-Medium 13pt you may set your custom font like so:

```
myTextField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"DIN-Medium" size:13.0f];
```

Comment: I actually have to use the PostScript name, not the full name

Comment: For those who don't know how to see the PostScript name in the Font Book — just press `⌘`+`i`.