# Custom Font Not Working in iOS Project

Tags: ios, xcode, fonts

I am starting a new project and trying to use a custom font but it is not working.

I have added this code and my font does not show up in the list of fonts.

```
let fontFamilies = UIFont.familyNames
for font in fontFamilies {
    let fontFamily = font
    print("\(fontFamily)")
}
```

It does show up as an option under custom fonts in my storyboard.

[image]

I have checked the usual things.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: send screenshot of output

Comment: Please Double check that your fonts are included as Resources in your bundle

Comment: I did that and posted a screenshot.

Comment: Ohh, i missed the screenshot, can you paste the log here. what does it print

Comment: @Vinaykrishnan It prints a list of all of the available font families and this one is not included in that list.

Comment: i agree with your point, it might happen that the name of the font you have added may be different one from the one you see

Comment: @Vinaykrishnan I am using the same font in another project and this code prints the expected font name.

Comment: The image you've shown for Info settings: `Fonts provided by application` ... add the extension to your font: `FranklinGothicStd-ExtraCond.otf`

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please copy your font file to Project check it it willautomaticaly added in copy Bundle resource.
[image]

Please change from atribute inspector area font will definatly reflected
[image]

Comment: The font file is in my bundle resources. I posted a screenshot of this.

Comment: Only copy your font file no need to add code it will automaticaly come in Custom font -> your font file name

Comment: All I did was copy the font file. The code I posted is simply to print a list of available fonts.

Comment: Please uninstall app once an try to reinstall it will work sometime problem with cache..and please remove code

Comment: otf fontfile sometime not work please use ttf file
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122087/add-otf-font-to-iphone-application?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: I uninstalled the app from simulator and the font still is not working.

Answer (score 0):

In info.plist key 'Fonts Provided By Application', I had to add the otf file extension to the font name.

Comment: Yes, this is what fixed it.